# As you notice vs As you see

Tags: usage

Let's say someone is talking to a teacher or a boss. Which sentence is more polite to be used:

```
As you notice, I have made major changes on the plan
As you see, I have made major changes on the plan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "As you notice..." or "As you see..." somehow makes it sound like their observation skills are inept that they haven't noticed the major changes.

Personally, I'd say, "Kindly/Please note that I've made major changes to the plan."

There are many ways to express your message. Also, the way a person delivers a message affects the politeness.

Comment: What if one say "As you **can** see" ?

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

> As you **may have noticed**, I have made major changes on the plan.

*notice* is a better word to use, because it allows the respondent to say "I did not notice" without much chance of starting a conflict.

You could use "As you **may have seen**..." but I would consider this more direct, and implies "You didn't **see** it?".